# Excel like column header options filtering algorithm

Tags: javascript, excel, algorithm, filter

In excel table when I set filter on one column it filters irrelevant filter options for another columns and so forth.

But I need to know what algorithm Excel uses to do this and if there's any implementations for JS.

I tried to update list of unique values for each column when new filter is being applied, but with this approach I lose unselected options on previous filter column. Excel somehow manages to keep them.

This question looks similar but it asks about specific implementation, what I need is algorithm or at least its name: [Angular JS Excel like filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35512473/angular-js-excel-like-filtering).

Pseudo code of current implementation:

```
var allRows: {[columnKey]: string}[]
var visibleRows: {[columnKey]: string}[]
var filterColumns: {[columnKey]: string[]}
var columns: { columnKey: string }[]
var uniqueValues: {[columnKey]: string[]}

/* when header menu opens it gets unique values
from the column as filter options */
function getHeaderValues(columnKey): string[] {
    return uniqueValues[columnKey]
}

/* when user applies filter this function is being called
to update visible rows and unique values */
function setFilter(filterColumn: string, values: string[]) {
    filterColumns = {
        ...filterColumns,
        [filterColumn]: values 
    }

    visibleRows = getRows(allRows, filterColumns)
    uniqueValues = updateUniqueValues(columns, visibleRows)
}
```

Comment: Hrm.. Look into the sources of e. g. [jqxGrid](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm).

Comment: `I tried to` implies that you did write some code. I'm glad to help you improve it, but I'm not going to write the whole algorithm for you. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I do not downvote questions on principle, but I think this applies here: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @masterfloda - Denis doesn't want your code - he wants _the_ algorithm or _at least its name_ from inside MS Excel. I wonder who is going to produce that for Denis.

Comment: This is a beautiful statement: **when I set filter on one column it filters irrelevant filter options for another columns**. Can you please clarify what it means to filter filter options and which ones are irrelevant vs. relevant?

Comment: I think it's not about algorithm. You can store filter options in variable for preventing from losing them after updating. It doesn't need a special algorithm.

Comment: @AliSoltani but we still need know filter which values can be applied and which not - just saving all filters doesn't help to help to figure this out

Comment: @IgorB I mean, you can store last filtered data and filters to handle filtering.

Comment: I think excel uses [Slicers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg399096(v=sql.110).aspx) for filtering data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea for an algorithm like this is that each filter is calculated based on the currently available data. When a filter is applied, the other filters recalculate based on the new set of currently available values. Consider the following data:

```
FOO BAR
===========
1   1
1   2
2   3
2   4
```

The filter for FOO will have values 1, 2 and the filter for BAR will have values 1,2,3,4.  When I filter FOO to 1, the sheet displays:

```
FOO BAR
===========
1   1
1   2
```

And recalculates available values for all filters. Now we see that BAR will only have values for 1,2.

**EDITED TO ADD FURTHER CLARIFICATION:**
1. Initial filter: all columns from complete data
2. Filter column A. Now column A is not recalculated, but all other columns are
3. Filter column B: column B is not recalculated, but all others including column A are
4. So you can't ever click on a filter that would result in no data
5. On Step 4, you do lose the option to filter column A by everything - but that's good! Because you can't filter A by something not available given the filter you have on B. That would result in empty set, but it's prevented by using this iterative approach to recalculating the filters

Comment: `When a filter is applied, the other filters recalculate based on the new set of currently available values`
We used the same idea for our initial implementation - but it works not like excel filters. If you apply filters for FOO=1 and check which are available - with your algorithm you would see FOO have available value 1 whenever in excel you can see both 1 and 2

Comment: Yes. I was trying to explain that with an example.

Comment: I think a simple fix for that would be to populate the filters by recalculating as I described, and adding whatever values are being used by your filter, then.

Comment: but when we have filter FOO=1, the filter FOO=2 falls out of both categories

Comment: Let me try again - my last one was sloppily written. When you filter on FOO, your recalculated filters use FOO as it already is, and only recalculate the other colums. If you then filter a seco d time using a different column, the filter for that column stays the same as at was, but all the other columns recalculate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166724/discussion-between-igor-b-and-tysonwright).

Comment: Thanks, @tysonwright .That's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Since not much context is provided, I am assuming you have an array of objects, each representing a row. For simplicity, we can assume each object looks something like the following:

```
const row = { col1: 'value1', col2: 'value2', col3: 'value3' };
```

To filter an array consisting of several rows in the above format, you can use the array `filter` function. This function gives you a new array containing the values (i.e., rows) that satisfy the filter condition while preserving the original array. A simple implementation for filtering column 2 to be equal to 'v1' or 'v2' is as follows:

```
const rows = [
  { col1: 'value1', ... },
  { ... }
];

const filteredRows = rows.filter((row) => row.col2 === 'v1' || row.col2 === 'v2');
```